# Why must I store a password column in my User domain if I'm using LDAP authentication?

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have a Grails application that uses the Spring Security Core and Spring Security LDAP plugins. I am using the bind method of authentication with an LDAP server as my only authentication provider. Why must I still store a password column in my database? My application has absolutely no need to store a value for a password, but it will not work if I remove the password field from the generated User domain class. Do I really have to store a password column with the value of null in my User table? Surely there must be a different approach to this.

Comment: Having a column with null values looks messy? I'm sure the code for the security plugin is not stable yet, I am on RC4, who knows how long it will take to get to v1.0

Comment: Spring Security doesn't require you to have a password column. I guess it is a Grails convention-over-configuration thing.

Comment: @holmis83 perhaps then my question should be, "How do I prevent Grails from persisting a domain property to the database?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you must!

simply define the password field as `transient` in your UserAccount class:

```
class UserAccount {
  String password
  static transients = [ 'password' ]
}
```

Comment: and just like that, I discover another aspect of Grails I had no idea existed :)